# Casting from AnyObject to CGColor? without errors or warnings

Tags: ios, casting, compiler-warnings, cgcolor, anyobject

Hello StackOverflow :)

I've been running into a weird problem since I upgraded to swift 2.0

I'm trying to set a border color, so I'm writing `self.layer.borderColor = borderColor as! CGColor` where borderColor is an `AnyObject`, while self.layer.borderColor is a `CGColor?`

If I write `self.layer.borderColor = borderColor as! CGColor` I get the warning

> Treating a forced downcast to 'CGColor' as optional will never produce 'nil'

and is recommended to instead use `as?`

If I instead write `self.layer.borderColor = borderColor as? CGColor` I get the error

> Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'CGColor' will always succeed

Just to make sure I wasn't missing something I also tried writing `container.layer.borderColor = borderColor as CGColor` and `container.layer.borderColor = borderColor`Both of these gave the following error:

> 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'CGColor'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Just running with the warning given by XCode when using `as!` is not all that terrible, but I would prefer to keep my code warning free. To avhieve that I really need your help SO. Is this something I'm not understanding or is it simply a bug in Swift 2.0 that I should instead report.

Cheers!

Jacob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xcode also gives me the following hint:

> Add parentheses around the cast to silence this warning

well... when xcode says so...

```
layer.borderColor = (borderColor as! CGColor)
```

Comment: This just makes the warning go away, it doesn't resolve the underlying problem. I'm myself looking for the correct answer so I don't know what it is, but I don't think that it's that.

Comment: This seems to have the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927167/trouble-retrieving-a-cgcolor-from-a-swift-dictionary

Answer (score 8):

You are using layer color, which is core graphics, you need to set core graphic color with property cgColor

```
layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: Good use of the UIColor cgColor property! Didn't even know this existed and Xcode didn't help me find it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a well-know bug and it is still unresolved! [Unnecessary message for non-optional to non-optional cast](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4209)

If you don't like the warning you should follow the Xcode advice:

> Add parentheses around the cast to silence this warning.