# Swift error while downcasting 'Any'

Tags: swift, downcast, optional-values

The following code is almost exact replica from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/identities/importing_an_identity) and compiles without errors:

```
guard let firstItem = (rawItems! as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>)?.first else {
    throw AnError()
}

let identityRef = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] 
               as! SecIdentity?   // !!!

guard let identity = identityRef else {
    throw AnError()
}
```

The line marked with `!!!` contains forced downcast, while replacing `as!` with `as` quite obviously results in a compilation error `'Any?' is not convertible to 'SecIdentity?'...` Indeed `SecIdentity` is a class while `Any` may not even be a class.

What I really cannot explain is the following. If I try to make the code safer, by using this

```
guard let idenity = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as? SecIdentity
else {
    throw AnError()
}
```

or this

```
guard let idenityRef = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as? SecIdentity?
else {
    throw AnError()
}
```

I get a compilation error: `Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'SecIdentity' will always succeed`

Comment: Do you get the `Conditional downcast...` compilation error for *both* `guard`s?--even for the first one with `as? SecIdentity`. The error makes sense for the last guard: every value will indeed succeed because even if `firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String]` isn't a `SecIdentity`, it will become `nil` when downcast to `SecIdentity?`, which satisfies that last guard (because of the optional `?`). This makes the guard useless, hence the compilation error. Did that make sense?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43927167/2976878

Comment: Daniel. How about the first example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SecIdentity` is *“an abstract Core Foundation-type object representing an identity, ”* and the type of Core Foundation types can be
checked with `CFGetTypeID()`. So you can check the type ID first. If it matches the type ID of an
`SecIdentity` then the forced cast is safe:

```
guard let cfIdentity = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as CFTypeRef?,
    CFGetTypeID(cfIdentity) == SecIdentityGetTypeID() else {
        throw AnError()
}
let identity = cfIdentity as! SecIdentity
```

See also the bug report [SR-7015 The CoreFoundation conditional downcast diagnostic is not as helpful as it should be](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7015):

> The diagnostic should be updated with a message that informs the developer to compare CFTypeIds (with a fixit if possible).

Answer (score 3):

CoreFoundation types behave a bit differently from Foundation types.

Don't conditional downcast the identity. If the optional binding succeeds you can force unwrap the identity

```
guard let idenity = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] else { throw AnError() }
var privateKey : SecKey?
let status = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identity as! SecIdentity, &privateKey)
```

Side note :

Please never write `as? SecIdentity?`.
Either it's conditional downcast `as? SecIdentity` or bridge cast an optional `as SecIdentity?`